# ios keyboard Done button presence in real devices for UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, ios-simulator

There are many questions out there on the "Done" button on the keyboard itself.
This question is about the **Done button that appears on the bar above the simulator's keyboard for a UITextView**.
This is a screenshot of my simulator:

[image: screenshot of my simulator]

You'll notice that above the keyboard, there is that bar with a Done button. If I click that button, the keyboard disappears completely.

I am happy with that behavior which seems to be there automatically. I don't have an iphone - I am testing on a simulator for now. My question is **on real devices is that UI and behavior always there or is it just there on my simulator?**

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Yes, if it's been explicitly added in code to appear above the keyboard for that particular instance. But that's not by default.

That isn't there by default, that's added using the `inputAccessoryView` property of a `UITextField`, and `UITextView`. We don't get that for free, we have to create it ourselves. But if you're concerned about it being visible on an actual device (on the screen you attached) then the answer is yes. But I don't want you to get the impression that you'll see that done button every time you see a keyboard onscreen.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: This is not clear to me. I personally haven't done anything in my code to add it. "But if you're concerned about it being visible on an actual device (on the screen you attached) then the answer is yes" - why is it always there in this case but not "every time you see a keyboard onscreen." Can you please be more specific about how to add it using the `inputAccessoryView`?

Comment: Did you inherit this code from someone else? What you're describing (and what's shown in the image) is not provided by default. If you were to create a new project and add a textfield you wouldn't see that bar with the "done" button appear above the keyboard. That's added by creating a custom view, and setting that view as the `inputAccessoryView` of the `UITextField`, or the `UITextView`. So what I'm saying is, if it's visible in the Simulator, then yes it'll be visible on the device, but that isn't standard behavior, so don't expect that to be the case in every instance.

Answer (score 0):

You will see the done button automatically without any code if you are using a `UIWebView` and textfield is present inside that webview. Is this the case?

Other than that as @pob21 stated, you can never get the `inputAccessoryView` without writing it in the code explicitly.